# just Failed unmounting /crdom

Tags: vmware, unmount

I tried to install ubuntu 22.04.3 in window 11 through VMware, I configure the virtual machine as usual but when it said restart for start using ubuntu, failed unmounting/crdom appear

[image]

Comment: Probably harmless.  Was there a question?  I don't see a question to answer.

Comment: Type `journalctl -b-1 -e` and (using the `?` command) search _backwards_  for `cdrom`. You may be able to see some related errors before the line you found in the log file.